# python-docx-template unexpected char in docx template

Tags: python, python-2.7, jinja2

I might have missed something or making a mistake, anyway I can't seem to access the data inside my dictionary in my .docx template. The documentation says it works like jinja2 but using `{{ dict['dict_key'] }}` gives me an error `unexpected char` even in `if` operations

```
{% for i in dict %}
    {% if dict[i] == 'key' %} 
        {{ dict[i] }} 
    {% endif %} 
{% endfor %}
```

as long as there is a `'string'` in my code it doesn't seem to work

I have been searching the documentation but I can't seem to find a solution
or maybe I missed it or did not understand it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working, I read it on [Github](https://github.com/elapouya/python-docx-template/issues/85) and it seems that there is a bug/issue on reading the document char format and raw copy/paste of the string makes it work.

Copying (from notepad++)`'String_with_string_Identifier'` to the `.docx` would print in the String without issues